# Is there a way to use more than one monad in one function?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a function

```hs
add2Maybe :: (Num a) => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
add2Maybe x y = do
    n1 <- x
    n2 <- y
    return $ n1 + n2
```

It will successfully return `Just 8` when called with `Just 3` and `Just 5`. What I want is when this fuction is called, similar to printf debugging in C, printing

```
The number in x is 3. --(Or Nothing).
The number in y is 5.
Final result is 8.
```

and return `Just 8`.

I concluded that to define a function like this, I have to use Maybe monad with IO monad, but the type signiture of `>>=` doesn't allow to use more than two monad in a single function. Is there a way to combine Maybe monad and IO monad, and more generally, is there a way to combine two or more monad types?

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a "monad transformer". Just as values of type `IO a` and `Maybe a` are monads, so too can be a value of type `IO (Maybe a)`. This combination uses [`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html).

However, this is a bit of an advanced topic, and will have you scratching your head if you are new to the concepts. If you just want to do printf-style debugging, consider [`Debug.Trace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) instead. It lets you cheat the type system to get text output when debugging, but should never be used in a finished program.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need `add2Maybe` implementation here it is

```
add2Maybe :: (Show a, Num a) => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> IO (Maybe a)
add2Maybe x y = do
                 mapM print x
                 mapM print y
                 return $ do 
                  n1 <- x
                  n2 <- y
                  return $ n1 + n2
```